# Case $1 bash script

Tags: bash, input, case

What do I have to do if I need to add 2 or more characters in codon?
Because codon only detects my first $1 input.

```
 for arg; do
        case "$1" in
            -n) shift
                codonnumber="$1"
                ;;
            -g) shift
                codon="$1"
                ;;
            [a-z]*) file="$1";;


        esac
        shift
    done
    echo codonnumber="$codonnumber" codons="$codon" file="$file"
```

Ex:
If i in "$codon":
root@pc3-03:~/Desktop# ./script.sh -n 4 -g AAA TGC sequence.fasta

It only detects AAA, NO AAA and later TGC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following:

```
[a-z]*) file="$1";;
```

matches the last two arguments `TGC` and `sequence.fasta`.  Essentially, the variable `file` is initially initialized to `TCG` and subsequently to `sequence.fasta`.

You probably wanted to say:

```
./script.sh -n 4 -g "AAA TGC" sequence.fasta
```

(Observe the quotes surrounding the arguments `AAA`, `TGC`.)

Comment: and if I want to run it without the " ". ie, changing case format??

Comment: @userbio I don't think that you'd be able to achieve the desired result without quotes.